# Still getting stuck with Mysql 2013 error after changing read time out

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm relatively new to database programming and I'm hoping someone can help me with this error since I'm out of ideas.

I keep getting "MySQL error code 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query".
I wrote a not-short and not-simple query with select statements embedded 2 or 3 levels deep in the "from" clause. Though I can't imagine in the grand scheme of queries this is particularly complex. When I copy and paste those inner queries into a separate tab and run them, they run in under 2 seconds. But when joined together into 1 query I'm getting this 2013 error. Under the "duration/fetch time" field it says somewhere between 50-60 seconds each time I try to make this work.

I've read other threads and the #1 recommendation is to increase the "DBMS connection read time out (in seconds):" in MySQL Workbench. I did that. And I'm still getting this problem.

I've also now tried this in 2 different locations so I highly doubt there's actually a connection issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Let's clean up the correlated subq's

Comment: 4 cubed exceeds a minute you may have timed-out.

Answer (score 2):

Try Changing your  max_allowed_packet to higher value.

Try `show global variables like 'max_allowed_packet'` for checking the current value 
and

`set global  max_allowed_packet = <higher value>`

You can set this in my.ini/cnf also

[Refer this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-lost-connection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below 2 variables value-

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%wait%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%wait%';
```

If below 600 then increase it to greater than what your query can take time, you can set 6000 for testing and then check your query, if still getting issue.

Further if you share you query then I can check if it can be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your tips. In the end I decided to do the right thing and find a way to make my query more efficient. I joined queries with each other 1 by 1 instead of joining them all together at once. Managed to get the query down to 6.7 seconds!